# Proof cofactor-matrix cofac(AB) = cofac(B)*cofac(A)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A \in K^{nxn}$ and $Cofac(A)$ be the cofactormatrix to A. I have to show

(1) $cofac(AB) = cofac(B)*cofac(A)$.

In fact I have:

$^t(cofac A) = cofac (^t A) = adj(A).$

Then I have (I have already proven it!!):

$adj(AB) = adj(B)*adj(A)$. So I get:
$adj(AB)= cofac(^t AB) = ^t(cofac AB) = ^t(cofac B) * ^t(cofac A)$.

That is not exactly what I wanted to show, but it's very close to it!?!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\adj}{adj}\DeclareMathOperator{\cofac}{cofac}$If I understand correctly, you have proven that $\adj(AB) = \adj(B) \adj(A)$, where $\adj(A) = \cofac(^tA)$. Then:
$$\cofac(AB) = \adj(^t(AB)) = \adj(^tB ^tA) = \adj(^tA) \adj(^tB) = \cofac(A) \cofac(B)$$

Which is the correct equation. Another proof is to notice that $\cofac(A) = \det(A) ^t(A^{-1})$.

Comment: Hello. If I first use $adj(A) = ^t(cofac(A))$ then I get: $cofac(AB) = ^t(adj(AB)) = ^t(adj(B)*adj(A)) = ^t(^t(cofacB)*^t(cofacA)) = cofac(A)*cofac(B)$. This is also correc,t isn't it? SO there fore the equation $cofac(AB)=cofac(B)*cofac(A)$ is NOT CORRECT?

Comment: Yes, your proof is also correct. And the equation you mention is indeed wrong.

Comment: Wow, and I tried desperately prooving the equation :D What about $ ^t (cofacA) = cofac(^t A) $ which then should be right. How can I prove this?